# Small problem in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have defined class ToolTipUI which extended BasicToolTipUI for propose of painting TipText of swing component, I used delimiter "|"(vertical bar) to differentiate two phase of TipText.
All text before this delimiter is considered to be the normal tooltip text and all text following this delimiter is considered to be the accelerator binding text.

As you know that vertical bar("|") is quite common character which usually used in a string. if it is a case of this, it shouldn't considered be delimiter and it have real meaning. for example:

```
label.setToolTipText("<HTML><BODY><LEFT>V1|V2</BODY></HTML>"); Normal use
label.setToolTipText("<HTML><BODY><LEFT>V1V2</BODY></HTML> | ctrl+v"); Use as delimiter
```

My problem is ToolTipUI don't know how to identify this different now, I cannot change the delimiter "|" to another unusual value for special propose.

Anybody have idea?

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you passing each parameter as a separate argument?

Comment: @Mark Elliot's idea is the best; add a second `setToolTipText` method that takes two strings.  If for some reason you can't do that, you could use the HTML code for that symbol: `&#124;`, so your parser would skip it, but since the label uses HTML, it should convert it to a vertical bar for you.

Comment: I use label.setToolTipText(String) to pass in,  since it come from Java swing component method, so I cannot extend every component class to pass each parameter as a separate argument

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use Mark Elliot's suggestion to pass the argument as two separate strings, then something along these lines might either help or make things worse:

```
  private int delimPosition(String s) {
    int eos = s.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf("</html>");
    return s.indexOf('|', eos+1);
  }
```

(To be used as a replacement for `s.indexOf('|')` that I'm guessing you are currently using).

Although I suspect you will probably end up with a significant degree of escalating complexity in this method, once all the corner cases have been worked out.  Maybe better to refactor now.